Synonyms concerning [osx] and [mac]
Should [mac] be synonymous to [osx]? Rarely would one refer to a mac machine without referring to the os, so they are pretty closely linked.
Should [osx] be renamed or perhaps made synonymous to [macos], as that is a broader term (similairly to [windows7] and [windows])?

I went ahead and merged [tag:osx] into [tag:mac]. If anyone starts (mis)using them more in the future we'll consider a synonym.

Good move @DavidPerry, I think mac is the better choice.

So far as I can see, there's only one mac question. And only one osx question. There aren't any macos questions. 
So I don't think we necessarily need synonyms at this point. Just pick a tag and re-tag the other question to be consistent. 

True enough. If the tags aren't in heavy use, it's probably easier to make the questions conform to the existing tags than to tweak the tags to fit the questions. Also, since folks use the existing questions to base their tag choices on, retagging the question might prevent future misuse of the tags.

Agreed.  The purpose of tags it to quickly find a solution or related solutions.  The current volume of solutions doesn't warrant that level of tag specialization.  It provides no benefit is there are only 10 mac solutions spread across 7 tags.  If in the future there are 8,000 [mac] solutions splitting tags and creating synonyms is more useful as 8,000 solutions becomes difficult to navigate.
